# How do we migrate questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

This question

https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/20391/why-do-people-in-media-always-refer-to-babies-as-females

Is about English usage.  It's not about parenting.  It would possibly fit on English.stackexchange.com

So what do I do to begin the migration process? I flagged it but the migration option was to meta., not english., so it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Since it's absolutely opinion based, and not true for a large majority of English speakers, it would be closed immediately there. So, better to not migrate.

Comment: I doubt ELU would ever be a target for this site (you never have more than 5 targets, even for [SO]), but Beta sites have only their per-site meta as a target - migration targets are added at graduation.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from [the StackExchange Meta migration FAQ.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) Emphasis below is mine:

> If you don't have 3,000 reputation, **the site isn't in the list of
>   available migration targets**, or the question got closed without being
>   migrated, do not fret. You can also **flag the question for moderator
>   attention and request that they migrate it for you**. Simply explain in
>   the reason which site you want it to be migrated (please select one
>   site; don't list all possible sites it could go to).

---

In this particular case, it's not actually clear whether this is an *English language* question, as some of the comments note:

- Where I live (different language), most unborn babies are referred to as "he"
- here it's almost always the other way round
- in Polish, we have such a wide range of pronouns that there is almost always a good choice

I'm going to defer to @anongoodnurse regarding migration since she has much more experience with ELU than I do :)